# What's A Good Option For Plug and Play FB page Customization?

Tags: facebook

I am looking for a good FB plug and play custom page service.  Something like pagemodo, but a little more robust.  Any suggestions?  I don't mind if we have to pay for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few alternatives to pagemodo for you to check out:

- [Shortstack](http://www.shortstacklab.com/)
- [Involver](http://www.involver.com/)
- [Tabsite](http://www.tabsite.com/)
- [SplashLab Social](http://www.splashlabsocial.com/)

Of these, I like [Shortstack.](http://www.shortstacklab.com/) Their pricing info is [here.](http://www.shortstacklab.com/pricing/) (I'm not affiliated with any of these services.)